# Reporting Services: Hidden field

Tags: reporting-services, hidden

I have a question regarding an `RDL` file that I generated. I have several rectangles, which I gave a hidden property with a function.

When rendering the report, the following occurs:

```
Rectangle 1 : hidden = false
Rectangle 2 : hidden = true
Rectangle 3 : hidden = true
Rectangle 4 : hidden = false
```

Now `rectangle 1 and 4` are shown, but there is an enormous gab between them, as `rectangle 2 and 3` are hidden.

Is there a way that the hidden rectangles do not use space, so they are really invisible, instead of hidden?

Comment: I'm not sure such a property exists. Perhaps you could try dynamically setting the size of the rectangle instead? That said I think it is more likely you are designing a report in an ineffective way. Is there perhaps a different way for you to achieve what you want? What is it that you want?

Answer (score 4):

Are the hidden areas eventually going to be expandable by some sort of user interaction? If so, you could set the Hidden = true, and set the ToggleItem to some other element to allow them to be opened/closed. This would have the rectangles collapsed and the extra space would not be taken.

One caveat - I'm not at the office to test this out right now, but they may need to be part of an overall table to do this. I'll check back when I get in and am able to test it.

UPDATE:

This solution works. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Add Rectangle to page
2. Add another element which will control Rectangle's visibility (this can be any element)
3. Set Rectangle Hidden property to true
4. The 'control' element will have a plus sign next to it which allows showing/hiding the rectangle

Comment: Many thanks! You can happily hide the "plus sign" element too (put it on the top corner or something then set its visibility to false).

Comment: Correction: Your toggler *cannot* be set to invisible if you want to be able to show the rectangle based on an expression. However, you can compress it a miniature size and no "plus" should be visible (nb: have not tested all format exports).

Answer (score 3):

Just had the very same (frustrating) issue with SQL Reporting Services 2008. Here was my scenario:

Rectangle 1 - (set page break after, conditional visibility)
Rectangle 2 - (set page break after, conditional visibility)
Rectangle 3 - (set page break after, conditional visibility)

I found that even when rectangle 1 was set to hidden it was still taking up space on the page so when I viewed my report I got

Page 1: <---- gap on page taken up by hidden rectangle 1 -->
Rectangle 2

Page 2:
Rectangle 3

What I ended up stumbling on was a property called ToggleItem which seems to be on most reporting controls. It's purpose is to allow you specify another control on the report that when you click it will show/hide the report item.

I added a single textbox named ToggleTextBox to my report and then set the following properties on my rectangles:

```
Rectangle 1: ToggleItem = ToggleTextBox
Rectangle 2: ToggleItem = ToggleTextBox
Rectangle 3: ToggleItem = ToggleTextBox
```

I then ran my report and this time that when rectangle 1 was hidden it didn't occupy space on the page at all and Rectangle 2 slotted. I exported the file to PDF and it displays the same as on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

I was running into a similar situation, I had a report that had a time frame parameter, Month, Quarter, and YTD. When month or quarter are selected the report has a set of tables per page for each quarter or month, when it's YTD it's just one set of tables on a single page. I created a set of tables and a textbox header for each quarter, month, and YTD, then hid them based on the parameter value. Whitespace kept appearing above the January report when you selected month, all the others were fine. I discovered that the whitespace was coming from 2 tables slightly overlapping, I moved the tables so they weren't overlapping and the whitespace disappeared.